# Laravel Mail Images not Show with Gmail

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, gmail

But it workes fine with another email service like temp mail etc.

**I used to SMTP of google mail**

Comment: Please provide the code of the email. Is it an inline image with src links, or are the images attached?

Comment: `<img align="center" alt="Image" border="0" class="center autowidth" src="https://invitosoftwaresolutions.com/testing/cardo/public/images/logo.svg" title="Image" width="124"/>`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need attach images into email body by cid (Content-ID), from security reason linked images are blocked.

Read more here - https://blog.mailtrap.io/embedding-images-in-html-email-have-the-rules-changed/.